# Why is my Jquery "animate" only firing once and not each time the function is triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm docking my navigation at a specific document height to the top of the viewport and when it's docked, it has a dropdown animation.

```js
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    var x = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(x>=700){
      $("header").addClass("fix");
      if($("header").hasClass("fix")){
        $("header").animate({top: '0'},500);
      }
      $("main").css("padding-top", "100px");
    }

    if(x<=300){
      if($("header").hasClass("fix")){
            $("main").removeAttr("style");
            $("header").removeClass("fix");

      }}
  });
```

```css
header{background:green}
main{height:2000px;background:yellow;}
#header{padding:20px; display: inline-flex;}
.fix{
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:-100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<div id="header">
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack overflow</a>
</div>
</header>
<main>
</main>
```

My problem is, after i scroll back up to the top of the page and scroll again down the page, the navigation pops up.
It doesn't drop down(show the animation), how can i fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/DamianToczek/rc05odu8/

(I wrote that code myself, not copy paste)

Comment: at a first view without any test  i suspect this `$("main").css("padding-top", "100px");` you add it in the first if, may it should be deleted in the second ?

Comment: Yeah, it must be added and deleted, because the header is position relative and i want it to go up together with the content and come back later. I've removed this padding and it doesn't work, you could test it yourself in the jsfiddle, so you would know that it won't fix the problem.

Comment: Why do you add fix then immediately test for fix?  What the point?

Comment: you aren't resetting the inline styles back to default.

Comment: Erik, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with plain CSS:

```
header {  
  top: -100px;
  transition: top .5s;
}

header.fix{
  width:100%;
  position:fixed; 
  top: 0;
}
```

Just remove the `animate` call from your js

Edit: Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1uw5req/)

Comment: A Jsfiddle would help me more, i don't understand what's the goal of that css.

Comment: I've added a link to a fiddle. The `transition` property tells the browser that when the `top` property changes, it should be animated. So adding the `fix` class causes the `top` to change and smoothly animate in

Comment: OHH! I see now, i never thought of this in that way, wow you open my eyes! Thank you dude!

Answer (score -1):

As the answer of @sklingler93 using CSS transition seems to be the best approach, the answer to the OP is :

1. as the scroll event triggers a lot of times the function, you should
   use `.stop()` before `.animate(...)` to be sure to not queue the animation.
2. you forgot to remove the style attribute of the header in your `if <300` statement.

Here is the answer with your code cleaned a bit as there were some useless instructions : https://jsfiddle.net/rc05odu8/2/

Or just the fix for your code is :

```
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var x = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (x >= 700) {
      $("header").addClass("fix");
      $("header").stop().animate({
        top: '0'
      }, 500);

      $("main").css("padding-top", "100px");
    }

    if (x <= 300) {
      $("main").removeAttr("style");
      $('header').removeAttr('style');
      $("header").removeClass("fix");

    }
  });
```

Comment: Same as what Felypp wrote : Would anyone mind to comment the downvote? Much better this way...

Answer (score -2):

I think in this snippet...

```
if(x>=(a-100)){
  $("header").addClass("fix");
  if($("header").hasClass("fix")){
    $("header").animate({top: '0'},500);
  }
  $("main").css("padding-top", "100px");
}
```

1. `$("header").addClass("fix");` should be inside the `if($("header").hasClass("fix"))`;
2. Probably `$("main").css("padding-top", "100px");` should be inside the `if` too;
3. You should negate the `if` expression;

This way you would have:

```
if(x>=(a-100))
{
  if(!$("header").hasClass("fix"))
  {
    $("header").addClass("fix");
    $("header").animate({top: '0'},500);
    $("main").css("padding-top", "100px");
  }
}
```

Makes much more sense to me.

Also, you must clear **all** the styles applied by the animation when the scroll is back at the top.

Hope it helps.